# Update a ruby array containing objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have an array of objects in ruby, how can I iterate over the array and update the object?

example:
`test_arr` has the following value: (fetched by a find_by_sql)

```
test_arr = [
  {"id"=>1024, "value"=>"9999"},
  {"id"=>1025, "value"=>"9999"} 
]
```

```
test_arr.map{|r| r.value="1111"}
```

returns 
    ["1111", "1111"]

I need something like: (after update)

```
[{"id"=>1024, "value"=>"1111"}>,
{"id"=>1025, "value"=>"1111"}>]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You must use `each`, because `map` is returning a changed array. `each` is iterating the array.

```rb
test_arr.each{|r| r.value="1111"}
```

With

```rb
test_arr.map{|r| r.value="1111"}
```

You return a changed array, the content is the result of the block (in the example it is "1111"). With `map!` the array is modified.

You may also use:

```rb
test_arr.map{|r| 
  r.value="1111"   # modify r
  r                # return r - you are replacing r with r
}
```

But as already mentioned: `each` will be better.

Comment: This will update the object in memory, but not save it. 
You will need to follow it with something like test_arr.map{&:save}

Comment: map does not change an array, it creates a new array.

Comment: You are right my 1st map definition is wroing. the detailed description later makes a difference between `map` and `map!`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to save it right away, try this:

```
test_arr.map{ |r| r.update_attributes( { :value => "1111" } ) }
```

If you need more performance than this, you could try update_all, and pass it the IDs from your array of objects. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all

Answer (score 2):

Actually your code should update attributes successfully. But I think you confused the `map` and `each` methods.

The `map` method iterates through the whole array and collects results from every iteration, that's why it's second alias name is `collect`.

What you need is `each` method, this one will just iterate through the array and do actions described in block.

So, your code should look like this:

```
test_arr.each { |r| r.value="1111" }
test_arr.inspect 
#=> [#<SimpleClass:0xb74c8968 @attributes={"id"=>1024, "value"=>"1111"}>, #<SimpleClass:0xb74c8940 @attributes={"id"=>1025, "value"=>"1111"}>]
```

Answer (score 1):

map iterates over the array and gives you a new array containing the results of the block.

```
test_arr = test_arr.map { |val|
   val.attr - new_value
   val # last line of the block is the return value
}
```

use [`map!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map-21) to update the array in place.

Comment: This will update the object in memory, but not save it. You will need to follow it with something like test_arr.map{&:save}